# How can compose messages without using launcher and chooser in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use SmsComposeTask for composing sms in wp7. but in my application i want to send messages directly without using SmsComposeTask so please tell me how can i send sms without using SmsComposeTask?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That's what the `SmsComposeTask` is for. The `SmsComposeTask` takes the action out of developers hands and ensures that the user gets to confirm whether or not an SMS gets sent and who to for security reasons. I'm sure user's would soon get annoyed if apps were sending messages out and using up their credit without their permission :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the functionality of the phone directly you can't.
You could, however use a web based solution for sending messages. i.e. your app calls a web service which sends the message.