# Send SMS in Windows Phone 7 or 8 C# application

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sms, sendmessage

I,am developing windows phone application.I want to send SMS to a another phone without using `SmsComposeTask`.Because i want send SMS directly clicking a button.
can i do this or not ?
If it can ,how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.Then the purpose of SmsComposeTask is lost. You can implement a Web Service to do the same without using SmsComposeTask

Refered from: [`How can compose messages without using launcher`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954663/how-can-compose-messages-without-using-launcher-and-chooser-in-wp7)

Comment: I'm new to .net.Have you done a Service to do this?.

Comment: @SandunHarshana Yes here is a sample , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7346/Sending-SMS-using-NET-through-a-Web-service . Just invoke the service method on your button click